# WPF how to force menu item bindings to update when menu opens

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a value that can change that doesn't raise a change event and the menu item bound to the value doesn't correctly reflect the state when the menu item is opened. I'd like to update this binding when the menu opens. How do I do this?

Can I have a menu item that just polls it's bindings each time the menu is opened? In this case the IsCommEnabled property:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding EnableComm}"  
    Command="{Binding Root.ToggleCommunications}"
    IsChecked="{Binding Authorization.IsCommEnabled, Mode=OneWay,         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

--

```
    public bool IsCommEnabled {
        get { return _communications.IsCommEnabled; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `SubmenuOpened` event, and manually update the binding:

```
void MenuItem_SubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MenuItem)sender).GetBindingExpression(MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Please note that the above applies to the Parent item being opened, so you may need to wrangle it a bit to ensure that it is the right item that is getting updated. You can use the Items collection on the MenuItem to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You have to raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` if you want to push the `IsCommEnabled` back to the bound `Dependency Property`

Comment: Right, but when the value changes it's not possible to notify at that point and time. Is there another way to force the update, say when the menu opens or is clicked or something?

Comment: You can do `GetBindingExpression(MenuItem.IsCheckedProperty).UpdateTarget();`